# Azure AppService deploy.cmd using the wrong file

Tags: kudu

I am trying to configure continuous deployment to a test server on Azure. The app is an ASP.Net application, but in this case that shouldn't really matter.

My build process (team city) produces a folder that has everything needed to deploy (minus some connection string info). If you point IIS at that directory it works great. If you FTP that directory up to Azure it also works.

I am tracking each of these builds in git and pushing them up to Github. So I am trying to use Azure deployment option to deploy from github. Everything is in git. The /bin folder included.

Kudu shouldn't need to do anything but a pull from git and copy all the files to wwwroot.

So I've set my .deployment file to be this:

```
[config]
project = .
```

Every time I do that, though, the deployment gives me the message:

```
Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --aspWAP "D:\home\site\repository\MyProj.csproj" --no-solution').
```

And it runs some generic autogenerated deploy.cmd.

If I delete the deploy.cmd from the cache, it regenerates some generic one.

And, most importantly, in doing all this, the WRONG ASSEMBLY IS BEING DEPLOYED!!

My app depends on System.Web.Helpers.dll. The correct version of this DLL is in github. I've verified this multiple times.

Kudu, however, is grabbing an OLDER one from NuGet and deploying that. And, of course, I get the dreaded YSOD error about not being able to load that file.

What do I need to do to make Kudu just copy the files from my github repository to wwwroot and nothing else?

Answer (score 2):

I wound up getting it to deploy by hand editing the autogenerated deploy.cmd file that lives at `\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd` in kudu.

I commented out the 2 autogenerated lines of:

```
:: 1. Restore NuGet packages
:: 2. Build to the temporary path
```

(commented out all the code underneath them, too)

And then hand-edited the 3rd section to run kudu sync from the DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE instead of the temp file like this:

```
:: 3. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)
```